# deliver In order data(FIFO) read from S3 - Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, fifo

I am reading data from S3 stored in folders by timestamp -2020/07/11/HH/MM/SS/file1.json. I can read the files and send them to Kinesis but I need to send it in order of the Timestamp(FIFO - Queue ??) and do it at a metered rate of 33K records/sec or 2 million/min. Current code is in Python but generates data unordered. Any  thoughts on how to achieve this ? The metered rate indicates using parallelism/threads to control the generated rate. Do I need to get a bounded number of folders(using threads) to pull data from S3 at a time and then send it to a FIFO Queue and then have a Consumer read it from the Q and send it to Kinesis ?

TIA,

Comment: Even if you can somehow get a multi-threaded app to send data to Kinesis in timestamp order, Kinesis is not a FIFO queue. You can simulate FIFO with a single shard, but once you move to more than 1 shard your Kinesis consumer will also be multi-threaded (one thread per shard) so there's no FIFO on the consumer end. If you really need FIFO, SQS is better (but much more expensive).

Comment: @devonlazarus The KinesisConsumer side is already handled with Flink Event Time.I am focused here on the Generator side to Kinesis.  Current thought is to pull data from S3 in parallel, sort by event timestamp in 1 place and store in a FIFO Queue/RingBuffer(??) and have another process pull data from this Data structure to send to Kinesis.